# How can I maximise the chances of getting my Area 51 proposal to work?

Tags: discussion, area-51

So, I've created an Area 51 proposal. I've emailed it / tweeted it to others and added it to my profile page. (The proposal has been deleted by now).

What other tips do you have? Is there a good way to frame a proposal? How do you get the views after it disappears from the front page?

I've asked two people whose proposals entered the commit phase how they got past definition and *both* said, "Don't know, it just happened!" =:-)

**Update:** after Tim Post's useful answer below, I need to clarify that this is meant to be a *general* question for all Area 51 user's, so not specific to my proposal.

Comment: Just out of interest... what happened to your proposal? I only ask as this question was posted in 2010, but there is currently a [Wiki proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92158/wikis) which was proposed Dec 2015.

Comment: @Greenonline: my proposal died. Thanks for the info, I have joined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do a little more in the description to convince potential contributors that the proposal could actually lead to a viable site.

I do realize that there are a number of options when it comes to wikis, but would an entire site devoted just to wikis attract a large enough community / receive enough traffic to sustain itself?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim. But just for clarification: this is meant to be a **general question**, not specifically about *my* proposal. I'll make that more clear in the question.

Comment: PS - I'll take your advice Tim.

Comment: @Mark - In general, if the proposal looks viable .. people start working on it and promoting it. You've already done (as far as I know) everything that everyone else has done as far as promotion. Granted, some people have more followers that might be interested. One tweet from Jeff on a new proposal usually results in a swarm of new followers.

Comment: @Tim - Jeff? Sounds like I should know his name, but I'm still fairly a newbie. After your last message I added to my description a bit but if you have any further or specific advice I'd like to hear it. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Mark - Jeff Atwood - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood (He runs Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange and the blog codinghorror.com)

Comment: @Tim - oh, Jeff. Of course I've heard of him (for some reason my brain stopped working). The funny thing is, I started following him on Twitter just 2 days ago... =:-)