# What do you do to promote your Area51 proposal?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Have you tried finding discussion boards to post a link to your proposal? How about comments on blog posts? Have you figured power search terms to find like minded people to invite? What about effectiveness of your efforts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best bet is just ask real questions and let Google take care of the rest.

For instance with Gaming.SE we have over 150 Starcraft 2 questions, if you ask a question that someone else is likely to have, they will start popping up in the search results.

This will draw more new users than me writing a blog post or sharing it on Twitter/Facebook...

So just keep asking real, expert questions and others will come

Comment: This is really a valuable advise. Now that I think of it my attitude towards the example questions was `let's get done with this` but as you say the questions are a real opportunity, not a burden.

Answer (score 2):

Well, make *sure* you avail yourself of the built in mechanisms for promoting!

During **definition** phase, click "share this"

[image: share this area 51]

During **commitment** phase, check the area underneath your commitment:

http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/2295/area51commitmentshare.png

(this is also how you build the referral numbers for the proposal that are attached to you in this proposal.)

Comment: Thank you Jeff, but the thing is, all my friends are non-programmers and have no interest in such site that I have proposed. And colleagues? I have none! So I cannot rely on my contacts, I'd have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59188/how-can-i-maximise-the-chances-of-getting-my-area-51-proposal-to-work) recently but that seemed to get interpreted specifically for *my* Q&A, about [wikis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia), thanks for asking... =:-)

For now I've relied on promotion via Twitter (which got exactly one extra follower) and Area 51 contributors.

I asked some more successful Q&A authors and they said it just happened by itself. So I guess it is about:

1. The subject and
2. (As Ivo said) the questions.

Comment: Mark sorry I posted almost the same question again, I didn't notice yours (bad excuse!). Thank you for the input here too.

Comment: @Majid - hey, no problem, thanks for taking the trouble to write. I think my question was not phrased well because you couldn't find it and it was answered in an unexpected (for me) way.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have done strictly nothing* :)

And it hasn't been very effective.

**Until now, answering this question with [a link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation) :)*

Comment: +1 for making me lough, and the link is welcome too, it is better than doing absolutely nothing! I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, one guy did say, *try to get Jeff to retweet your proposal on Twitter*!  =:-) (true) I tried but, no luck. =:-)

Comment: Ha ha! I got him post an answer on this question though!

Answer (score 0):

You could put [StackImage flair](http://stackimage.quickmediasolutions.com) on your blog or as your signature on forums.

I have mentioned this on a couple sites with some positive feedback.