# What is a good information resource on the SE model?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51

Prompted by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121614/138112) which I think contains a valid requirement -

Suppose I want to try to convince a (technical/IT/programming/other) mailing list or forum to switch to SO, or a SE site.

What is a good, concise, to the point resource that explains in layman's words

- How the SO/SE model works differently from forums / mailing lists (with step-by-step demonstration of answers, voting, comments...)
- What the benefits are in terms of building a long-term information resource (less noise, outdated information floats to the bottom, etc.)
- How editing works (you can edit broken links, typoes, add relevant information, etc.)
- How the reputation system works
- How moderation is valued, and a narrow on-topicness focus maintained
- Where the model has already succeeded (Mention Stack Overflow; quote notable newspapers / online resources / tech gurus praising the model; show Alexa stats)
- How SE sites come into fruition

etc. etc. ?

It should be illustrated or even a video or presentation; it should be understandable to laypeople as well as techies. It should be to the point - it would serve more as *advertising* for the SE network than as an information resource.

[The "about" page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) doesn't really cut it - it is too general. All the information I'm asking for already exists, but it is scattered across the web - for example, I've seen interviews with Jeff, blog posts and Meta posts where he beautifully formulates why the SE model rocks. But it's scattered, that's the problem. The FAQ are way too specific.

I guess this is kind of a feature request, so I'm tagging it as such.

Comment: You should mention that the FAQ doesn't really cut it, and *convince* is a strong word, maybe *inform*?

Comment: Or at least "try to convince"

Comment: @Bobby added a paragraph about the FAQ. Chris - good idea, reworded.

Comment: Perhaps this is something for Jeff to do as a "handover" document before he departs :)

Comment: `typoes` -> `typos`. I didn't edit the question, because it's only one character, though.

Comment: I did do [this](http://prezi.com/zc8jpz8qwgyc/stackexchange-2-minute-intro/), once upon a time ([related meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91447/130064)). (Click More>Fullscreen for better view)

Comment: @Benjol nice! It's not 100% what I'm looking for but definitely worthy of an answer IMO.

Comment: I just [realized that the Stack Exchange About-Page](http://stackexchange.com/about) actually does a very nice job already. Could be better, but a good starting point.