# Where to post this question: "On which internet site can I post technical-oriented polls"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am posting to Meta implying "I am unsure to which Stack Exchange Q&A site to post this question, help me figure to which Stack Exchange Q&A to post it".
The question is

> "If I want to post regular *polls* on certain computer/technical topics, on which existing popular internet site can I do this (not SE) (radiobutton-style polls) ?"
>
> Please nota bene I am not talking about polls on SE here. No way.

Comment: There is not a single forum on the Stack Exchange network. There are only Q&A sites. And you are correct, no support for polls. Poll-type questions aren't welcome either at least on the sites I'm familiar with.

Comment: I case you were wondering: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Calling SE sites *fora* is an easy way to attract downvotes.

Comment: But first question is valid, "which stackexchange Q&A site is valid for this question", no ?

Comment: Yes it is valid...more or less.

Answer (score 5):

1. Not here.
2. Yes, this is correct, we're Q&A, not polls.

Ironically, we [were just talking about the missing description about what Stack Exchange is exactly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121623/what-is-a-good-information-resource-on-the-se-model). But the [about page of Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about) will give you some ideas.

Comment: But first question is valid, "which stackexchange Q&A site is valid for this question", no ?